# Storage account reporting history

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I need to know how a storage account was growing in storage capacity.

I would like to have the last 6 months

If I see in the insights or metrics there is only the last month

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure monitor metrics are (mostly) stored for 93 days, after which they are removed. If you want to store 6 months worth you will need to look to export them to Log Analytics and set the retention on your workspace to 6 months.

This won't help with metrics that have already been deleted, but will allow you to store them in the future.